# giving each file a proper html5 tag based on MIME type to be displayed in an html+bootstrap template

Tags: java, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a web server in java that basically list all the files on a device. I want to create a cool, responsive UI using bootstrap to display those files on the client's browser; however, I know that just creating an link to each file won't get me anywhere.

Here is some code before I continue:

```
for (File f : files.toArray(new File[files.size()])) {
    filesAsLinks += "<a href=\"/Files"
            + f.toURI().getPath().replace(":", "") + "\">"
            + f.getPath() + "</a>" + "<br>";

}
```

I am thinking to create a `Handler` that is responsible for giving the file that it receives a proper html5 tag. For example:

```
Handler.handle (String path) {
    Path source = new Path(source);
    String contentType = Files.probeContentType(source);
    // last two lines to get the content type of a file 
    if (contentType.startsWith("video")) {
        return "video width=\"320\" height=\"240\" controls> "
                + "<source src=\"pathRelated/video.mp\" ;type=" + contentType + " >";

    }
}
```

Would that be the relatively right thing to do before even thinking about making a template with bootstrap, or should I make the template first?

So far I have been replacing the generated links String with a simple html template that contains some placeholders like "ContentGoesHere" in the following template:

```
"<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"> "+
                    "<head>"+
                    "   <title>Max Server</title>"+
                    "</head>"+
                    "<body style=\"width: 100%; height:100%;\">"+
                    "   <table width=\"100%\">"+
                    "       <tr>"+
                    "           <td colspan=\"2\" style=\"background-color: #FFA500;height:10px\">"+
                    "               <h1>  HTTP Server</h1>"+
                    "           </td>"+
                    "<td colspan=\"1\" style=\"background-color: #FFA500;height:10px;white-space: nowrap;\"></td>"+
                    "       </tr>"+
                    "       <tr>"+
                    "           <td style=\"background-color: #FFD700; width: 100px;\" valign=\"top\">"+
                    "               <b>Menu</b><br />"+
                    "               <a href=\"/Files/\">Files</a><br />"+
                    "               <a href=\"/messages\">Messages</a><br />"+
                    "               <a href=\"/contacts\">Contacts</a><br />"+
                    "               Settings<br />"+
                    "               Info"+
                    "           </td>"+
                    "           <td style=\"float: left; margin: 5px;width:100%\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">"+
                    "               ContentGoesHere"+
                    "           </td>"+
                    "       </tr>"+
                    "       <tr>"+
                    "           <td colspan=\"2\" style=\"background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;height:20px;\">"+
                    "           
                    "           </td>"+
                    "       </tr>"+
                    "   </table>"+
                    "</body>"+
                    "</html>";
```

The final result string (template+content) is written to the client's socket output stream and sent to the client.

Comment: If you want to use HTML5 tags, you should declare your document as HTML5 using `<!doctype html>` at the beginning.  
Apart of that, what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

> I know that just creating an link to each file wont get me anywhere

Simply creating a link would work - it would open the video and the browser would handle the actual viewing of the file based off the mime-type of the file you are accessing.

If, on the other hand, you want to display each item on the same page so you have a nice format *and* the files being shown (think YouTube or another site), then creating the html for the different elements would be correct. I would advise creating the html based off the file extension rather than off the mime-type.

To your "which first" question, that is up to you. You can start with the template or the content within the template, depending on your work flow and what you are most comfortable with.